# Managing project build notes in version controlled environment

Tags: git, version-control, build, merge, release-management

We have recently tried to make things a bit clearer, for our testers, when releasing a new project build.

Our initial idea was to include a Markdown file named "BuildNotes" in the project (which is source controlled). We edit the markdown file, which then generates an html page that they can read.

In the file, we have a section at the top named `Build-Next`. So if you are completing a User Story, finishing a task or completing a bug, you then make an entry in this section on your branch, which is then Merged into the main branch via a PR.

e.g.

#### Build Next

- `BUG 1234` Button does not work

#### Build-6

- `User Story 5` Button click saves document.

Now when the Branch is merged into develop, and then the next build is pushed up. The document is updated and all the items from `Build Next` are moved into the new Build section, e.g. `Build-7`.

This works well if you are working on 1 task, then the task is completed and you move onto the next one. However, if you are working on multiple small bugs in their own individual branches, and have 3/4 branches sitting waiting for a PR, you are then stuck with constant merge conflicts every time 1 branch is completed, then the other branches will all have conflicts with the file since you are always updating the `Build Next` section.

Is there some other way we could do this? We can tag our PR's with the Bugs/Tasks in Visual Studio online, and these then show in the build, however we often put in custom notes in the Build document so the testers know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

For small bugs which exist in individual branches, if them are not related, you can build them separately. Use continuous integration(CI) build in build definition, so every time when a branch merge into main branch, a build will be triggered.

If these bugs are related, you should solve the conflicts until all the PRs are merged into main branch, and then start next build.

Comment: Often the bugs are completely unrelated, so they are kept on separate branches and are attached to their own work items.

Comment: So you can merge them separately, and in the main branch it will easy to view the commit histories.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should change the approach. Instead of a single version controlled document, you should have the build process generate the *Build Document* document as an artifact. For example, you can have tiny per-branch notes (e.g. `branch-note-BRANCH_NAME.md`) and the build simply append them to the master document which is not version controlled (or lives in its own repository).

You will have two build flavors: one on master that concatenates the per-branch note files into the *Build Next* section, another on develop that concatenates int o a *Build N* section. You can pick the build identifier using some API of your build tool or by tagging the repo during build.

Comment: We had thought of this, but then we were thinking of how the build would know which notes need to be moved from "Build Next" to the next Build section.

Comment: Added some ideas on answer